# How do I hide team members' contacts information from other teams within one Team Project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have an existing team working on one solution using Visual Studio Online. Now I have to add new developer to work on one of the projects. Due to security concerns I have to hide other team members' contact details and ideally names as well.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to have everyone working in the same team project and keep this information hidden. There are ways to minimize the avenues through which someone can see the information -- for example, you could isolate the one developer into their own team, so names/emails wouldn't show up on the team's home page -- but if they're working on the same code in the same repository, they'll be able to see things like commit history, which will definitely have identifying details attached.

Comment: I appreciate your response but i need to separate, there will be many temporary contractors and they cannot mess with permanent team at any circumstances. That's the main reason. or maybe somehow with branch would it be possible?

Comment: Your question said *view*. *Mess with* implies changing. You can easily restrict the ability to change settings.